# How to identify login user with Social Connect Magento Extension

Tags: magento-1.8, development, module, third-party-module, social-buttons

I am using [Inchoo Social Connect Magento extension](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/social-connect-magento-extension/comment-page-1/#comments)

which is working fine but my concern is that how can i identify user is login by which account? if email address are same for Google and Facebook account. its return me in **login customer session** Facebook id and and Google id both.

I need to determine this information just because when user enter there comments in product detail page[product comment is my custom module]. I'll display there Avatar picture from Google/Facebook account.

Any one please help.

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I have not used this extension but have simply looked at there code in [github](https://github.com/Marko-M/Inchoo_SocialConnect/).*

It appears that each login action creates an item in the registery containing the user data. You should be able to check which item is there from the following:

1. inchoo_socialconnect_linkedin_userinfo,
2. inchoo_socialconnect_twitter_userinfo,
3. inchoo_socialconnect_facebook_userinfo,
4. inchoo_socialconnect_google_userinfo,

Answer (score 1):

This inchoo extension identify customer login by  using customer attributes

```
inchoo_socialconnect_lid for linkedin
inchoo_socialconnect_fid and inchoo_socialconnect_ftoken for facebook
inchoo_socialconnect_gid for google
inchoo_socialconnect_tid for twiiter
```

This code depend on  current version of inchoo extension https://github.com/Marko-M/Inchoo_SocialConnect/

Comment: For using above extension do i need to Valid OAuth redirect URIs in fb app. And if possible can you add how to use the extension

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL query below :

```
select email,updated_at,core_website.name,core_store.code,attribute_code,value from eav_attribute inner join customer_entity_text on eav_attribute.attribute_id=customer_entity_text.attribute_id inner join customer_entity on customer_entity_text.entity_id=customer_entity.entity_id inner join core_store on customer_entity.store_id=core_store.store_id inner join core_website on core_store.website_id=core_website.website_id where eav_attribute.attribute_code like "inchoo%id";
```